# Mount PVC in cronjob and statefulset

Tags: cron, kubernetes, persistent-storage, volumes, statefulset

I have two services that I would like to access a PersistentVolumeClaim.

One is a StatefulSet that is reading from the volume (and serving content to end users), the other is a Kubernetes CronJob that periodically updates the contents of the data in obtained by a PVC.

Right now I'm running into the issue that my PVC is backed by a PV (not NFS, Ceph, or the like) and one service grabs the volume making the other not start.

How can I make it so both of these services have access to the volume?

And is there a way to add a CronJob to my StatefulSet the same way I add more containers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked the `accessModes` of your `pv` and `pvc`?

If you want more than one pod to be able to mount the volume you'll need to use `ReadOnlyMany` or `ReadWriteMany`

[Persistent Volume Docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes)

As for your second question, no, there's no way to "add a CronJob to [a] StatefulSet". They are separate and distinct API objects.

Comment: Thanks friend! In that case I just need to make it so my CronJob runs on the same pod as my StatefulSet, right?

Comment: Update - I ended up just hacking it and removing my CronJob. Then adding it as a container in my StatefulSet so it will now run as an interval. My PV only has accessModes ReadWriteOnce. Yay beta features. Thanks for the help friend :)

Comment: According to the docs that you pasted, access modes are about nodes, not pods. You can mount a pvc on multiple pods on the same node, even if set to ReadWriteOnce.